# Spring boot JpaRepository manytomany findBy contains all values from the list param

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

Is there a way to find entities which contains all items from the list param?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "parent_child")
    private List<Child> children;
}
```

for example i have a few parent objects with different children IDs:

```
1) [10,20,30]
2) [10,20,40]
3) [10,30,40]
4) [20,30,40]
```

and i want to find all parents which contains both children IDs "10" and "20" - so only 1st and 2nd parents match

but this query gives me all 4 entities, because each one contains any "10" or "20"

```
List<Parent> findDistinctByChildrenIdIn(List<Integer> children);
```

so for now there is only one way to do it - retrieve one list using "10" (parents 1/2/3), then another list using "20" (parents 1/2/4), and then find intersection of these lists  (parents 1/2).

but i'm not sure that's a good idea, want to delegate this logic to spring jpa

Comment: Hint: you should be able to use `children.size()` as a parameter and compare it to the count of matching children (`ID IN :children`)

Comment: `IN` generates an `or` query, in your case you need an `and`. so may be criteria query will help